# The SD card and external hard drives are not readable on tablet BQ M10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bq, aquaris, m10

when I connect an external hard drive or SD card to my tablet BQ M10, I see them do not appear in the shortcut menu of the file manager. When I put MP3 files on my SD, it will not appear in music.
On my phone E5 BQ HD, it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This may be bug [#1592421](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ciborium/+bug/1592421)  which is should be fixed in OTA-12.

Comment: thank you, you think it will come out when?

Answer (score 0):

A microSD card which can be read when inserted in the slot, can also be read when connected through USB to a microSD card reader.

When a USB hard disk is connected, it is not recognized by file manager, even when connected through a powered USB hub.

When a USB thumb drive is connected, it is also not recognized by file manager. It does appear as an item under the "External Drives" tool, i.e. "SD Card Management". However, an attempt to eject the device produces a "device busy" error message.

Conclusion: The BQ M10 is intended reject storage devices which are not microSD cards, but fails to do this cleanly when a thumb drive is connected.

Comment: not as a USB key inserted into my phone E5 works and my M10 tablet does not work.